# Exporting empty cells to csv comma-delimited file from datagridview

Tags: c#, excel, csv, datagridview

First off, I am still fairly new to programming, so please forgive any lapses in knowledge or terminology I may offer.

I am building a C# application that first imports data from an Excel workbook into a set of datagridviews (One dgv per worksheet). The user can select a custom range of cells from each datagrid, and then click a button to export the selected range to a CSV file. To this point, I have most of what I need working, but the problem I am having is that it is skipping over blank cells at the end, and I need those to be included in the final output of the csv. For example if cells A1 through A3 have a value, but A4 does not, and the user selects the range A1 through A4, the final csv needs to output as:

```
1,2,3,
```

However, the way I have it now, it only outputs `1,2,3`. If there are multiple blank cells at the end of the range, it does the same thing, and we need those accounted for.

To note, if the blank cell occurs anywhere within the range, it works fine...it is only if the cells are empty at the beginning or end of the range that this seems to happen.

If I reset any blank or null values to " ", it works as a workaround, but I would prefer the end-file to not have any blank-type values in it.

I appreciate any help. Here is my code that handles this export functionality:

```
    private void exportClick(DataGridView dgv)
    {
        Int32 selectedCellCount = dgv.GetCellCount(DataGridViewElementStates.Selected);
        int CurrentRow = 0;
        int CurrentColumn = 0;

        Excel.Application xlApp;
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
        Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
        xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

        if (selectedCellCount > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < selectedCellCount; i++)
            {
                // Get the Row and Column index values
                CurrentRow = Convert.ToInt16(dgv.SelectedCells[i].RowIndex.ToString());
                CurrentColumn = Convert.ToInt16(dgv.SelectedCells[i].ColumnIndex.ToString());

                // Set cell to current cells' value
                DataGridViewCell cell = dgv[CurrentColumn, CurrentRow];

                // Check if the cell Value is empty, set to ??? so a comma is written
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(cell.Value.ToString()))
                    cell.Value = " ";

                // Write the value to the worksheet 
                xlWorkSheet.Cells[CurrentRow + 1, CurrentColumn + 1] = cell.Value;
            }

            // Prompt to save the results as a csv file
            if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {

                xlWorkBook.SaveAs(saveFileDialog1.FileName, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlCSV, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
            }
        }

        xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
        xlApp.Quit();

        releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
        releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
        releaseObject(xlApp);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `non-breaking space` using `ascii` like:

```
 if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(cell.Value.ToString()))
     cell.Value = char.ConvertFromUtf32(160);
```

Or any other invisible characters in the ascii table, like:

```
 Delete - 127
 Soft Hyphen - 173
 Unknown - 129 or 141
```

Or perhaps you could just use a special character that would indicate as empty that
would not be most likely used by the users, like those letter `e` that have
characters above like:

```
 232 - with grave
 233 - with acute
 234 - with circumflex
 235 - with diaerisis
```

Then when you process it later on you could identify those characters as empty or space
using the character that you have chosen.

Comment: Thanks Edper. Ultimately, I decided to just skip the output to Excel and am writing the output to a text file using a Pipe delimiter. Since Excel csv's just comma-delimit results by default, we needed to find a different method for this as some of our data may contain commas. I appreciate the feedback though!

Comment: @svenGUTT Good that you find a work around according to your needs. Happy coding and GOD bless!